# Retrofit Call.enqueue method not being called - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

i was able to make Edit and Delete work in a test project, using Retrofit2, but now i needed to used it in my real project, and despite the code and webservice used (created using Slim 4 and Notorm)  are the same,  both Edit and Delete started not working for some reason (get and Post both work correctly)

For both Edit i am using a page that get all the date from the DB and put it in some views,  and  then i click in a button that have the Edit Function .  I tried debugging and everything is fine, until it tries to enter the call.enqueue method, and it fails, without giving any error on my logcat.  I have a toast on my onResponse and another toast on my OnFailure and neither shows on my screen.

With the Delete the situation is similar i have a page, with a call.enqueue (on the on.create) that gets all the data that appears in the views,  and then a button that trigger the delete method, and here also the call.enqueue doens't work.   I tested this, without having the call.enqueue on the oncreate, but it happens the same thing.

Here is my Edit button code

```
fun editar(view: View) {

    val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(EndPoints::class.java)
    val latitude = latitude.text.toString().toDouble()
    val longitude = longitude.text.toString().toDouble()
    val morada = editMoradaView.text.toString()
    val n_quartos = editNQuartosView.text.toString().toInt()
    val casaBanho = casaBanho.text.toString().toInt()
    val contacto = contacto.text.toString()
    val mobilada = mobilada.text.toString()
    val preco = preco.text.toString().toDouble()
    val observacao = observacao.text.toString()
    val utilizador_id = shared_preferences.getInt("id", 0)


    if (isBitMap) {
        val base = getBase64String(decodedByte)
        fotografia = base
    } else {
        fotografia = base64
    }

    val call = request.editar(
        id = ID,
        users_id = utilizador_id,
        morada = morada,
        n_quartos = n_quartos,
        latitude = latitude.toString().toDouble(),
        longitude = longitude.toString().toDouble(),
        fotografia = fotografia,
        preco = preco,
        ncasas_banho = casaBanho,
        telemovel = contacto,
        mobilado = mobilada,
        outros_atributos = observacao

    )

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<OutputEditar> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<OutputEditar>, response: Response<OutputEditar>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {

                val c: OutputEditar = response.body()!!
                Toast.makeText(this@EditarAnuncios, c.MSG, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val intent = Intent(this@EditarAnuncios, MapsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<OutputEditar>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@EditarAnuncios, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    })

}
```

Here is my Delete Button Code

```
 fun delete(view: View) {

        var id = intent.getStringExtra("PARAM_ID")
        var idString = id.toString()
        val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(EndPoints::class.java)
        val call = request.apagarAnuncio(id = idString.toInt())


        call.enqueue(object : Callback<OutputApagar> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<OutputApagar>, response: Response<OutputApagar>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val c: OutputApagar = response.body()!!
                    Toast.makeText(this@DetalhesAnuncioLogado, c.MSG, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    val intent = Intent(this@DetalhesAnuncioLogado, MapsActivity::class.java)
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
                    finish()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<OutputApagar>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@DetalhesAnuncioLogado, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        })

    }
```

Here are my 2 data classes (in separated files)

```
data class OutputEditar(
    val users_id: Int,
    val morada: String,
    val n_quartos: Int,
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double,
    val fotografia: String,
    val preco: Double,
    val ncasas_banho: Int,
    val telemovel: String,
    val mobilado: String,
    val outros_atributos: String,
    val status: String,
    val MSG: String

)

data class OutputApagar(

    val status: String,
    val MSG: String
)
```

Here are my endpoints

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/editar_anuncios/{id}")
    fun editar(@Path("id") id: Int?,
               @Field("users_id") users_id: Int?,
               @Field("morada") morada: String?,
               @Field("n_quartos") n_quartos: Int?,
               @Field("latitude") latitude: Double?,
               @Field("longitude") longitude: Double?,
               @Field("fotografia") fotografia: String?,
               @Field("preco") preco: Double?,
               @Field("ncasas_banho") ncasas_banho: Int?,
               @Field("telemovel") telemovel: String?,
               @Field("mobilado") mobilado: String?,
               @Field("outros_atributos") outros_atributos: String?): Call<OutputEditar>

    @POST("/apagarAnuncios/{id}")
    fun apagarAnuncio(@Path("id") id: Int?): Call<OutputApagar>
```

Both Endpoints work well on my  Test Project  and on Postman

My Service Builder

```
object ServiceBuilder {

    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://tneveda.000webhostapp.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T {
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }


}
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That moment, when 10 minutes i made this Question, i found out my problem. Forgot to update my Endpoints on my Real Project, and that is why it was not working